# vb.net serialization of system objects?

Tags: vb.net, serialization, serializable

I am working with sending objects over network. I have it working with custom objects just fine but my question is can I serialize system objects? For example I want to serialize the System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface  object on one computer and send it to another so I can load all of its properties easily. Is this possible? This doesn't seem to work:

```
  <Serializable()> NIC As System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you trying to serialise it, and what errors are you getting?

Comment: what ype of serialization? XML/JSON/Binary? And then are you sure you would serialize an abstraction of a concrete object?

Comment: I am using XML right now but could switch to binary if needed.

Answer (score 0):

An object type has to be designed to be serializable, and marked so in it's original code. You will need to build your own object to keep the properties that you care about, mark it serializable, and use that.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. There are a lot of properties and I was trying to be lazy and just send the whole object then have to program all of the ones I need :) which could be a lot of them. I don't want to have to re-invent what is already there!